# How do I add an id to a iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iFrame that I want to give an id to:

```
<iframe id="whatever"></iframe>
```

How could I do this?  (I would prefer to not use javascript or jquery)

Comment: You just did, to "whatever"

Comment: Not sure you're providing enough context for your specific case. Can you not modify the HTML itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about a static ID that you can assign in the HTML then you have already done it in your example by using the `id` attribute.

```
<iframe id="whatever"></iframe>
```

If you mean dynamically assigning an ID when the page is loaded in the browser or at some point during user-interaction, then you will need to use either a technology that dynamically generates the HTML upon serving it to the client (e.g., .NET, Java, Python, PERL, Ruby) or you will need to use web-compatible scripting (e.g., JavaScript) to do it in response to some user-interaction on the page.